# Apache Ignite 2.7.5 delete cache and free up memory

Tags: java, caching, ignite, gridgain

We are using Apache Ignite (version 2.7.5) as a 2-node PARTITIONED cluster with ignite persistence enabled.

Each of the 2 ignite instances has a cache (say, named XYZ) which is taking up ~ 250 GB space in each of the instances. This table has 150 million records.

Going forward we don't need this cache any more and I want to delete this cache and reclaim space (disk space as well as off-heap memory) in each of the instances.

I have tried the following:

1. Tried writing an API to remove all data from the cache and destroy it.

   ```
   @DeleteMapping(path = "/delete-cache")
    public String deleteCache() {
        try {
            IgniteCache<XYZId, XYZ> cache = ignite.cache("XYZCache");
            cache.removeAll();
            cache.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOG.error("Exception while destroying cache: ", e);

            return "Fail";
        }
        return "Success";
    }
   ```

   But on hitting this API, Ignite hangs and my service loses connection with Ignite.
2. Tried deleting the cache by going inside the ignite instances and doing an `rm cache-XYZ`. After doing this the disk space got reclaimed by the ignite instances could never start up as a cluster together. There was no specific error in the ignite logs but doing an:

`./control.sh --baseline` did not give any result and the terminal hanged.

Currently, there is an API to delete the objects one by one given the `id` of the record, but this is going to take 8 weeks to delete 150 million entries with the current rate.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run just `cache.destroy();` (without deleting each entry)
It will destroy the cache and reclaim the space on the disk.